# tenho o seguinte codigo, mas esta dando erro para digitar a variavel letra. como solucionar?

Tags: c, c++

> 1. Faça um procedimento que recebe as 3 notas de um aluno por parâmetro e uma letra. Se a letra for ‘A’, o procedimento calcula e
>    escreve a média aritmética das notas do aluno, se for ‘P’, calcula e
>    escreve a sua média ponderada (pesos: 5, 3 e 2). Faça um programa que
>    leia 3 notas de N alunos e acione o procedimento para cada aluno. (N
>    deve ser lido do teclado)

```
#include <stdio.h>


void media (int a,int b,int c,char let){
  int media;
  switch(let){
    case 'A':
    media= ((a+b+c)/3);
    printf ("A média aritmética é %d\n",media);
    break;
    case 'P':
    media= (((5*a)+(3*b)+(2*c))/10);
    printf ("A média ponderada é %d\n",media);
    break;
   
  }
}

int main(void) {

  int notaa,notab,notac,alunos;
  char letra;

  printf("Digite quantos alunos:\n");
  scanf("%d",&alunos);
  printf("Digite a primeira nota:\n");
  scanf ("%d",&notaa);
  printf("Digite a segunda nota:\n");
  scanf ("%d",&notab);
  printf("Digite a terceira nota:\n");
  scanf ("%d",&notac);
  printf("Digite A para uma média aritmética e P para uma média ponderada\n");
  scanf ("%c",&letra);
  media(notaa,notab,notac,letra);

  for (int i=1;i<alunos;i++){
  printf("Digite a primeira nota:\n");
  scanf ("%d",&notaa);
  printf("Digite a segunda nota:\n");
  scanf ("%d",&notab);
  printf("Digite a terceira nota:\n");
  scanf ("%d",&notac);
  printf("Digite A para uma média aritmética e P para uma média ponderada:\n");
  scanf ("%c",&letra);
    media(notaa,notab,notac,letra);
    
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite não sei, se conseguiu mais tenta colocar o 's' ao invés de 'c' no scanf.

`

```
  printf("Digite [a] para uma media aritmetica e [p] para uma media ponderada\n");
  scanf ("%s",&letra);
```